# C# - Can't send HTTP Post Request with valid JSON

Tags: c#, json

I have .Net 4.0.

I'm trying to send a web service (that I don't control) a http POST request with a header and data, but I'm getting a 500 internal server error.  The web service sends text messages to cell phones - I have an account that I've successfully tested through their web site, so I know my "contact list" is valid

Their API documentation calls for the following:

Headers: Content-Type: application/json

Data: For example to send the message ‘Testing’ to the contact id ‘1111’ you would POST:

```
{
"contacts": [1111],

"text": "Testing"
}
```

Here is my code that is returning the 500 error:

```
        WebRequest MessageRequest;
        WebResponse MessageResponse;
        JavaScriptSerializer jsSer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        object JSONSerialized = new object();
        string jsonString = @"{ ""contacts"":""ValidNumber"",""text"":""test text""}";

        JSONSerialized = jsSer.Serialize(jsonString);
        MessageRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL);
        MessageRequest.Method = "POST";
        MessageRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

        using (var strWrt = new StreamWriter(MessageRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            strWrt.Write(JSONSerialized);
            strWrt.Close();
        }

        MessageResponse = MessageRequest.GetResponse();
        //^^^This is the line that throws the 500 error.

        return MessageResponse;
    }
```

Regarding the formatting of their request.  I've tried

I have tried strWrt.Flush() between Write() and Close() and still got the 500 error.

I have tried building the json as a Dictionary, sending the string as a byte array with strWrt.Write(), among other things I've seen suggested, but all of those resulted in a 400 Bad Request error.

Also, I've tried many variations of formatting their data.  I realize this example has quotes around the phone number and doesn't have the brackets as depicted in their docs, but I have tried all of those combinations and always get the 500 error, so I'm *guessing* that I'm either not converting the string to a json object correctly, I'm not passing the json object to the MessageRequest correctly - or both.  Most of the solutions I've found use .Net 4.5 objects and, unfortunately, the web service's support wasn't helpful at all - they only said "it looks like you're not sending valid json"

I've been stuck on this for a week - any help would be **greatly** appreciated.  Thanks for your time.

Update:

I changed to another SMS API which worked on my first try.  Although none of the suggested solutions worked for this question, it isn't important to me, anymore, although I am a bit curious as to why it never worked.

Comment: What does fiddler (http://fiddler2.com/) tell you is going over the wire? I generally would use RestSharp for this kind of code, but my recollection is that JavaScriptSerializer expects a DTO with public properties matching the property names.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose the elements (even just one) in your array between [ ] for example

```
{
  "contacts":[{1111}], "text":"msg here"
}
```

Comment: Thank you - how do I pass that to the Message Request?  I've tried an object with a uint[] named contacts and a string named text and got a 400 error.  I also tried it with an object with two keyvaluepairs(<string, uint[]> and <string, string>) named contacts and text and also got a 400 error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have missed in the API definition that you provided that the contacts are passed in as an array of numbers

```
{ "contacts": [1234, 4321], "text": "hello" }
```

instead of a single string value

```
{ "contacts": "1234", "text": "hello" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't get why do you need `JavaScriptSerializer` when you have serialized object already? Why not to pass it as it is? Now it's seems you are trying to serialize some object twice. Try the following code:

```
    WebRequest MessageRequest;
    WebResponse MessageResponse;
    string jsonString = @"{ ""contacts"":""ValidNumber"",""text"":""test text""}";

    MessageRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL);
    MessageRequest.Method = "POST";
    MessageRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

    using (var strWrt = new StreamWriter(MessageRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        strWrt.Write(jsonString);
        strWrt.Close();
    }

    MessageResponse = MessageRequest.GetResponse();

    return MessageResponse;
```

Comment: I have tried this code and it throws a 400 Bad Request error,